# rails 5.1.4 console in production doesn't find models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I think I got a configuration issue with my rails setup in production.

I've got a puma working fine without any issues (connecting to db, loading models etc) and previously was able to use the console (I've encountered this [bug][https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19256] but worked around it by filling in the database.yml)

**When I try to open the console to perform little operations, none of my model classes are found.**

```
✗ bundle exec rails console production
Running via Spring preloader in process 18313
Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.4)
irb(main):001:0> User.count
NameError: uninitialized constant User
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>
```

Similar questions on SO recommend to run `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses` and eventually `Rails.application.eager_load!`

When I do try to run `Rails.application.eager_load!` I get uninitializaed constant error

```
irb(main):005:0> Rails.application.eager_load!
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController
Did you mean?  ApplicationCable
        from app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):5
```

So I guess my console is now somehow lost and hasn't loaded the project source correctly.

How can I troubleshoot this situation ?

**edit 2018-02-15** : I connected my workstation to the prod environment to use the console. This worked at first, the console was behaving correctly. After a couple times the same issues appeared. After doing `spring stop` I was able again to user my local workstation to open a console in prod. 
Interesting fact : this never happens in dev environment, although spring had an app running in this environment.
It turns out spring is also running in prod, although the spring gem is only in dev group. (see below)

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rails-erd', require: false, group: :development
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.2'

group :production do
  gem "sidekiq"
  gem "sentry-raven"
end

gem 'pg'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'i18n-country-translations'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'i18n_alchemy'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Comment: Do you run this on a production server, or on a local machine?

Comment: On the production server

Comment: do you use Heroku or something else? If you're using Heroku, you might try issuing the `heroku run rails console`. If it's already set up to be a production environment. Additionally, have you tried with setting the `Rails.env = "production"`, and then running `rails console production`?

Comment: no, I am running in aws. I've also tried using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`

Comment: Can you check you have a file called `application_controller.rb` in your `RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers`. The fix might be as easy as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568039/uninitialized-constant-applicationcontroller-nameerror-application-works-fin)

Comment: I was able to open a console to this db from another box. I suppose this related to the thread or db connection pool, how can I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: added more infos in the original question

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on my production machine running 5.1.4 under Passenger.  Running `spring stop` resolved it.

Comment: This question is quite old, but @dan 's suggestion actually did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed through Docker make sure using `-ti` prefix in running command like:

```
docker exec -ti 4d318d505e9f rails c production
```

Comment: -ti means to run rails c in an interactive shell, and the number 4d318d505e9f refers to a docker image in which this shell is to be opened. I've no idea how what you wrote even relates to the question.